# Python intersection on list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have list of dict say :

```
   data:-[
{
    "cat_nbr": 4,
    "cat_name": "STORE",
    "l_id": "15.8",
    "size": 19,
    "f_type": "EPIC",
    "p_type": "single"
},
{
    "cat_nbr": 4,
    "cat_name": "STORE",
    "l_id": "63.9",
    "size": 192,
    "f_type": "EPIC",
    "p_type": "single"
},
{
    "cat_nbr": 5,
    "cat_name": "UN_STORE",
    "l_id": "54.0",
    "size": 191,
    "f_type": "EPIC",
    "p_type": "single"
}
```

Here i want to create a list based on cat_nbr and cat_name and append to existing list. I want to do intersection based on cat_nbr and cat_name, if same add to that list or elase create a new object My output should look like this:-

```
"catalogs" :[
{
  "cat_nbr" :4,
 "cat_name" "STORE",
 "flist" : [
{ 
     "l_id": "15.8",
      "size": 19,
      "f_type": "EPIC",
      "p_type": "single"
 },
 {
  "l_id": "63.9",
   "size": 192,
   "f_type": "EPIC",
   "p_type": "single"
 }    
 ] //flist closed for cat_nbr 4 and cat_name STORE
 }, //cat_nbr 4 and cat_name STORE close
{
  "cat_nbr" :5,
  "cat_name" "UNSTORE",
  "flist" : [
 { 
     "l_id": "54.0",
     "size": 191,
     "f_type": "EPIC",
     "p_type": "single"
 }
 ] //flist closed for cat_nbr 5 and cat_name UNSTORE
 ] //catalogs closed
```

This is my code looks like:-

```
   def get_catalog_data(data):
    catalog_result = []
    for item in data:
        catalog_dict = {}
        catalog_dict['flist'] = get_flist(item)            
        catalog_result.append(catalog_dict)
       //Logic to add in the same cat_nbr and cat_name
    return catalog_result
```

Comment: Can you post what have you tried, any issues in code?

Comment: @neilharia7 added the existing code .need to add some logic to add to get the common cat_nbr and cat_name

Answer (score 0):

For these types of tasks, [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) is a very compact solution. It is a slightly different format than what you were originally going for, but maybe you could use it anyways:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data).groupby(by=['cat_nbr', 'cat_name']).agg(list)
df_exploded = df.apply(pd.Series.explode)
```

Output df:

```
                          l_id       size        f_type            p_type
cat_nbr cat_name                                                         
4       STORE     [15.8, 63.9]  [19, 192]  [EPIC, EPIC]  [single, single]
5       UN_STORE        [54.0]      [191]        [EPIC]          [single]
```

Output df exploded:

```
                  l_id size f_type  p_type
cat_nbr cat_name                          
4       STORE     15.8   19   EPIC  single
        STORE     63.9  192   EPIC  single
5       UN_STORE  54.0  191   EPIC  single
```

Or if you really require the dict-list structure, you could convert back using:

```
catalogs = {}
for index, row in df_exploded.iterrows():
    if index not in catalogs:
        catalogs[index] = []
    catalogs[index].append(row.to_dict())
```

Note that I took the intersect as a key for a dictionary instead of the list structure that you used. This should nevertheless be usable.

Result:

```
{(4, 'STORE'): 
[{'l_id': '15.8', 'size': 19, 'f_type': 'EPIC', 'p_type': 'single'}, 
 {'l_id': '63.9', 'size': 192, 'f_type': 'EPIC', 'p_type': 'single'}], 
(5, 'UN_STORE'): 
[{'l_id': '54.0', 'size': 191, 'f_type': 'EPIC', 'p_type': 'single'}]}
```

Comment: @user:14578331 My output format should look like this {"cat_nbr" :4, "cat_name": STORE', "flist": 
[{'l_id': '15.8', 'size': 19, 'f_type': 'EPIC', 'p_type': 'single'}, 
 {'l_id': '63.9', 'size': 192, 'f_type': 'EPIC', 'p_type': 'single'}], 
{"cat_nbr"5, "cat_name": UN_STORE', "flist": 
[{'l_id': '54.0', 'size': 191, 'f_type': 'EPIC', 'p_type': 'single'}]}

Comment: How to modify the index name

Comment: The index name can be modified using pandas.Index.rename. In this case that would be df.index.rename([list of new names]). Regarding your list format: I think that my answer should carry you 90% of the way, I am sure that you will be able to manage the last 10% by yourself

Answer (score 0):

Following @C Hetch answer on using a tuple as dict key, but using defaultdict as an alternative to pandas,

```
from collections import defaultdict
catalogs = defaultdict(list)
for item in data:
    catalogs[(item['cat_nbr'],item['cat_name'])].append({key:value for key,value in item.items() if key not in ['cat_nbr','cat_name']})
```

It doesn't completely answer your question but can lead you the way.